# How to purge definitively sensible data from JVM memory?

Tags: java, string, security, architecture, garbage-collection

Does anyone have suggestions on how to purge a sensible data from memory definitively?

This data is card credit data , so, i need to guarantee that this data will be removed.

I've been reading about char[] and it seems to me that i never should use Literal String because String will be live until garbage collector want to get this String.

But...
I need to request a Rest API using this decrypted data, so when i'll set the object on xml format, inevitably needs use String.

Help me please, guys!

Comment: Encrypt the data before writing it to the XML

Comment: Before asking such a question you should present your threat model. What capabilities does the attacker have? Or which class of attacks do you wish to mitigate?

Comment: What?! You are sending unencrypted sensible data over the network, but worry about what is in your RAM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sort of a wasted exercise honestly :/ There's persistent page tables, crash dumps, heap dumps, cpu caches, thread caches, rowhammer attacks, freeze attacks, the JVM's String implementation itself, and many servers like Tomcat implement string pools, among many things I don't know.

Nevertheless, if you're *determined*, and sometimes you're just trying to check a stupid box of a "security" [theater] audit, you could conceivably store it as a `char[]` or `byte[]` and do an `Arrays.fill(array, 'x')`

Comment: I don't have choice about it, because i need to write the code following this rules:
[link] (https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI%20SSC%20Quick%20Reference%20Guide.pdf)

That software will be validate by an audit process.

Comment: I the audit is as stupid as that, perhaps `array = null;` resp. `string = null;` may already make the audit happy.

Comment: Good luck @ThiagoRoberto, if you think my answer is useful, please don't forget to "check" the answer and accept it so I get the reputation points for answering your question.